# Searching a string in a file having format unicode

Tags: python

I have a file that issaved as unicode

I tried the following code to search that string in unicode file

```
file_name="test_string"
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        if file_name.lower() in line.lower():

            return 1
```

But above code is working for AASCI coded files. Please help me to find the string in unicode encoded files.

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding. The file might be encoded in `UTF-8`.

Comment: Unicode use either UTF-8, which maps Unicode code points to variable-length sequences of octets, or UTF-16,

Comment: If you use Python 3 then have a look at the third parameter of [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). If you use Python 2.x use [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Does it print an error message? If so, copy-paste the error message. Does it give the wrong answer? If so, describe the answer that it does give. Does it do something else? If so, please describe what it does.